# How to use mongodb timestamp datatype in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to query oplog ts field in mongoose, not able to do so since mongoose does not support Timestamp bson data type? Any idea how to query ts in code?

I need to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291671/119031) query on mongo shell.

Comment: You have a lot of libraries, to get timestamp in moongose https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-timestamp

Comment: need to use mongodb Timestamp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use mongodb Timestamp directly from the mongodb module as in the following example **[The MongoDB Oplog & Node.js](https://www.compose.io/articles/the-mongodb-oplog-and-node-js/)** which demonstrates querying the oplog for the highest timestamp :

```
var MongoDB = require('mongodb');

// get the oplog URL
oplogurl = 'mongodb://<user>:<password>@candidate.11.mongolayer.com:10240,candidate.0.mongolayer.com:10240/local?authSource=wiktory'

// open db connection 
MongoDB.MongoClient.connect(oplogurl, function(err, db) {  

    // get oplog collection
    db.collection("oplog.rs", function(err, oplog) {

        // find the highest timestamp
        var ts = new MongoDB.Timestamp(0, Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)),
            query = { "$gt": ts };

        // create a tailable cursor and set it to await data
        cursor = oplog.find({ ts: query }, {
            tailable: true,
            awaitdata: true,
            oplogReplay: true,
            numberOfRetries: -1
        });

        // wrap that cursor in a Node Stream
        stream = cursor.stream();

        // log to console when data arrives
        stream.on('data', function(oplogdoc) {
            console.log(oplogdoc);
        });

    });
});
```

---

With mongoose, you can say for instance connect to to the local database where the oplog is found:

```
var MongoDB = require('mongodb');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/local')
```

Once a connection is established, you can then use the same concept as above to use a tailable cursor on the "oplog.rs" collection using the `mongoose.connection.db.collection('oplog.rs')` object, for example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoDB = require('mongodb');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/local');  

var conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
conn.once('open', function callback () {

    var oplog = conn.db.collection('oplog.rs');

    // find the highest timestamp
    var ts = new MongoDB.Timestamp(0, Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)),
        query = { "$gt": ts };

    // create a tailable cursor and loop each oplog entry
    oplog.find({ ts: query }, { tailable: true }).each(function(err, entry) {
        if (err) { /* handle error */ } 
        else {
            // log new oplog entry                                                                                                                                           
            console.log(JSON.stringify(entry));
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: thank you for the relevant link, i am long way into mongoose and was wondering if it was possible to use Timestamp there. Otherwise I will have to maintain a separate connection just for this.

Comment: @dhaval No worries, happy to help :)

Comment: any idea on why the first parameter is set as 0 here for Timestamp, because when I get it from mongo it is set as 1

Comment: The first parameter in the [**`Timestamp()`**](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/timestamp.html) constructor represents the low (signed) 32 bits of the Timestamp so when it comes from mongo it is 1 since it represents the the first 32 bits which are a `time_t` value (seconds since the Unix epoch). For more info, refer to the docs [**here**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps)