# Mongo BSON Types in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I use `Timestamp()` and other mongo shell operations mentioned  in [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) using mongoose?

If I do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276725/mongodb-read-search-timestamp-based-on-oplog/25291671#25291671), I get an error :

```
oplogModel.find({ts: {$gte: lastTimestamp, $lt: Timestamp(currTimestam
                                                    ^
ReferenceError: Timestamp is not defined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006218/which-schematype-in-mongoose-is-best-for-timestamp?

Comment: Do not change your question from the original form. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects like [`Timestamp`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Timestamp.html) are defined in the native driver package.

You can reference the underlying node native driver by calling `mongoose.mongo`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Timestamp = mongoose.mongo.Timestamp;
```

That will allow you to set up imports and use functions defined in the driver for BSON types.

Note that "not all" helpers in the shell are available. Only those that actually make sense ( such as BSON type definition functions ) are actually made available in all drivers.

Also note that in most cases you really want `Date`. Which will be a BSON `Date` object, that is actually just stored internally as the milliseconds from epoch value anyway. But of course deserializes as a `Date` object that would be the most commonly used for the language in question.

`Timestamp` is a specialised case, and it's not like you really gain anything on the storage between the two.

Comment: `var Timestamp = mongoose.mongo.TimeStamp;
oplogModel.find({ts: {$gte: lastTimestamp, $lt: Timestamp(currTimestam
                                                        ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Timestamp is not defined.

Comment: @Shipra It's `mongoose.mongo.Timestamp`. The import does not use the correct case. My Typo.

Comment: Can I use Date object or epoch timestamp to compare to the BOSON timestamp stored in the oplog?

Comment: @Shipra That is not the question you asked. Bottom line is whatever the BSON type of data you want to query, that is the type you must supply. Note that when using mongoose, then you should probably not be trying to set a schema on the collection, since you are likely to get the wrong types. Anyway, this answers the question you asked. If you have other questions then [Ask Another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @Shipra No you will not. Do not change your question from what you asked. You have another question to ask so [Ask another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Changing your question from what you ask is particularly rude and confusing since existing responses will be out of context. That is not the sort of behaviour that does well here. If you want a good experience here, then follow the rules. Accept that what you asked was answered and move on to a new question.